# Possible to convert spa pump motor to bench mounted grinder?

Tags: wiring, electric-motor, hot-tub

I just added the pictures. I would like to know if it's possible to convert a motor that came out of a spa (magnetek brand) into a bench grinder.

The plug has 2 round poles, with a rectangle pole between them. They are arranged diagonally across a rectangle plug-head.

There is a wiring diagram that shows it can be set up for "high voltage" and "low voltage". I have not taken any covers off to see how it's currently configured. I'm in the U.S. and would want it to run on household current. (some call it 110v some call it 120v)

I did finally see the Amperage, and it's 16.0 or 8.0 
[image: Spa Motor Plug]
[image: Spa Motor Label]

Comment: Can you post a picture of the label and plug? Also ANSI C84.1 calls supply 120v, NEMA calls utilization equipment 115v.

Comment: I have not taken the pictures yet, but I did look at the label again. It does say 115 or 230v. Couldn't find Amps, but I was holding this heavy motor in an awkward position trying to read it, so I might have overlooked it. :-)

Comment: @NoSparksPlease Added pictures.

Comment: Another thought crossed my mind, and that's to see if it has a decent re-sale value, and maybe I'd be better off selling it instead of trying to make something out of it.

Comment: That is a lot of power for a bench grinder .

Comment: @blacksmith37 That's what I was starting to think. I demolished and discarded a hot tub, but when I saw the motor, I thought it was probably still good for something, so I kept it. The only thing I thought of for myself was a grinder, but I certainly don't need that much power for one. I don't want to invalidate existing, good, answers. Otherwise I'd edit my question to be just about converting the plug to U.S. Mains and maybe about ideas on what to use it for.

Comment: 16A is the maximum amperage allowed for a single cord connection on a 20A circuit (210.21(B)(2)). Probably should use a 1 hp rating receptacle. I'm a little stumped about how CSA lets them leave the HP line blank. Maybe Canada doesn't require it, looks like a Canadian motor since it doesn't have US subscript below the symbol.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease -- btw, the motor does seem to have a US (UL) approval (as per the UL file # on the label) but it's a component recognition as UL didn't start listing ordinary-location motors until *very* recently.

Comment: @3ØEel It is odd there is an apearant file number but no mark,  kinda makes me scratch my head.

Answer (score 4):

A spa pump motor is usually what's called a "C face" design, meaning that the motor mounts directly to the pump, which is what mounts to the spa. When you take it off of the pump, you have no mounting feet, so no way to hold it to your bench. So yes, you can use a spa pump motor for other things, but it will require some substantial mechanical engineering to make it into a grinder. Also, a typical grinder has a shaft on both ends, a pump motor has only one.

From an electrical standpoint, you need to read the nameplate of the motor to know what it requires and if it is adaptable to 120V household current. They often are, but then the next issue might be how MUCH current it will pull. The practical limit for a typical 120V outlet in a residence is 12A (80% of 15A), which means the motor must be 1/2HP or less. Many spa motors are 3/4HP or 1HP, so you would not be able to legally connect that to a standard 120V 15A receptacle.

Comment: The label should show Amps, for a 115/230v motor it will show two numbers, the low number is high voltage, the large number is low voltage.

Comment: It’s *illegal* to connect a 3/4 HP motor to a 15A receptacle?

Comment: @Canadianer I have not seen a direct NEC reference, but UL rating of most heavy duty (Lev 5262) 15A are rated at 1/2 hp, some 20A (Lev 5362) are rated for 1 hp.

Comment: And now we know that the motor is rated for 16A at 120V, so that confirms it cannot be connected to a basic 15A outlet. Yes, it could be connected to a 20A outlet, but that is not "standard" in most residences in North America.

Answer (score 2):

All of the spa pumps I've replaced have had some sort of mounting brackets on the motor so it could be set on a bench. The problem it that the motor single shaft either has no threads on it and attaches to the impeller with a straight coupling    or it has 1/2 to 3/4" of threads that screw right into an impeller. Either way, trying to fit a grinding wheel that's usually 3/4 to 1" thick to it safely would prove challenging. Also, bench grinders have wheel guards, safety shields, built-in switches and lights in some cases. These would/should be added for your own safety. I think your best option would be to buy a new one at your home store.

The electrical info JRaef mentions definitely needs to be taken into account.